# How To Create A Function For Zencart To Target If Mobile (mobile devices)

Tags: php, function

Trying to create a function to target mobile devices to set the number of columns per row to 1 for mobile devices, in product grid view on mobile devices.

There is a number of columns per row setting within the Zencart admin interface, which is set to 3, which is perfect for desktop devices, shows 1 row of products in "portrait" mode on mobiles, but in landscape mode on mobiles it shows rows of 2 products, with overlapping images.

Need help creating a function to set the rows of products to 1 for all mobile views (if the columns per row setting is changed to 1) all mobile views are perfect, but desktop, then only gets rows of 1, instead of 3.

```
 function isMobile() {
 if(isMobile()){
 $columns_per_row = defined('PRODUCT_LISTING_COLUMNS_PER_ROW') ? PRODUCT_LISTING_COLUMNS_PER_ROW : 1;
 $product_listing_layout_style = (int)$columns_per_row > 1 ? 'columns' : 'table';
 if (empty($columns_per_row)) $product_listing_layout_style = 'fluid';
 if ($columns_per_row === 'fluid') $product_listing_layout_style = 'fluid';
 $max_results = (int)MAX_DISPLAY_PRODUCTS_LISTING;
 if ($product_listing_layout_style === 'columns' && $columns_per_row > 1) {
 $max_results = ($columns_per_row * (int)($max_results / $columns_per_row));
 }
 if ($max_results < 1) $max_results = 1;
 $listing_split = new splitPageResults($listing_sql, $max_results, 'p.products_id', 'page');
 $zco_notifier->notify('NOTIFY_MODULE_PRODUCT_LISTING_RESULTCOUNT', $listing_split->number_of_rows);
 }
 }
```

Basically it's just setting this to 1 for mobiles:

```
$columns_per_row = 1;
```